# How to hide and show elements based on current hovered element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We need to be able to hide and show elements based on currently hovered element. We have tried the following below, but it does not add the `is-active` class and remove it based on what other element is on hover.

How can we hide and show elements based on the current hovered element?

**Goal (based on example below):**

1. when you hover over `some` under `first`, display `<div class="two" id="some-link">some link</div>` using `is-active` class
2. when you hover over `path` under `first`, `<div class="two" id="some-link">some linke</div>` should not display (remove `is-active` class), and `<div class="two" id="path-link">path link</div>` should display (add `is-active` class)

**Current issue:**

1. `is-active` class is not being removed when on hover element is changed

```js
$(function() {
  $('li#two').hover( function() {
    var el_two = $(this);
    var el_id = el_two.attr('id');
    var el_link = el_two.attr('data-at');
    var el_sel = '#'+el_link+'.'+ el_id;
    var el_parent = el_two.parent().parent();
    el_parent.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
    $(el_sel).addClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.two {
  display: none;
}
.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> first</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li data-at="some-link" id="two">
          <a href="#"> some</a>
        </li>
        <li data-at="path-link" id="two">
          <a href="#"> path</a>
        </li> 
        <li data-at="another-one" id="two">
          <a href="#"> another one</a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="two" id="some-link">some link text</div>
        <div class="two" id="path-link">path link</div>
        <div class="two" id="another-one">another one</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> second</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> another some</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> another path</a>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> third</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> third some</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> third path</a>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: your data attribute is `data-at` not `data-link`: `el_two.attr('data-link')`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I did fix that typo, but the `is-active` class is still not being removed from the previous element.

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/1Ksbz3uR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `.find()` is using the wrong selector. You have `find('is-active')` which is an element name selector, you wanted a css class selector ie `.is-active`.

```
el_parent.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
```

Note for `removeClass()` you don't use a css selector you just use a class name hence why you don't need the dot in that call

Now if you wanted to also have the class removed on hovering out of the element as well then you need to add an event listener for that, and call removeClass from there. `.hover()` uses a second argument for setting such an event listener callback.

```
$('li#two').hover(onHoverCallback,function(){
  //code for finding the right element
  $(el_sel).removeClass('is-active');
})
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('li#two').hover( function() {
    var el_two = $(this);
    var el_id = el_two.attr('id');
    var el_link = el_two.attr('data-at');
    var el_sel = '#'+el_link+'.'+ el_id;
    var el_parent = el_two.parent().parent();
    el_parent.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
    $(el_sel).addClass('is-active');
  },function(){
    var el_two = $(this);
    var el_id = el_two.attr('id');
    var el_link = el_two.attr('data-at');
    var el_sel = '#'+el_link+'.'+ el_id;
    $(el_sel).removeClass("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
.two {
  display: none;
}
.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> first</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li data-at="some-link" id="two">
          <a href="#"> some</a>
        </li>
        <li data-at="path-link" id="two">
          <a href="#"> path</a>
        </li> 
        <li data-at="another-one" id="two">
          <a href="#"> another one</a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="two" id="some-link">some link text</div>
        <div class="two" id="path-link">path link</div>
        <div class="two" id="another-one">another one</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> second</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> another some</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> another path</a>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="one">
    <a href="#"> third</a>
    <div class="one">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> third some</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"> third path</a>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. Another alternative i found was to use `.toggleClass()` in place of `.add()`